# Fatal error: Constant expression contains invalid operations in

Tags: php

> Fatal error: Constant expression contains invalid operations in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba\php_pruebas\app\controller\auth\Token.php on
>   line 18

```
protected $token = [

        'csrf' => random_int(0, 500) // line 18
    ];
```

Buenas ese es el error que me salta. Necesito que ese espacio me genere un numero al azar pero me da error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu código debería lucir de este modo:

```
<?php

class Demo
{
    protected $token;
    public function aleatorio()
    {
        return $this->token = random_int(100,200);
    }
}

$obj = new Demo();

echo $obj->aleatorio();
```

Dando como resultado, por ejemplo:

> 120, 150 o cualquier otro número en ese rango de 100 a 200

**Explicación**

> Por lo que veo el error pudiera estarse generando por que intentas
>   asignarle un valor dinámico a una propiedad de la clase

**Opción 1**

- La propiedad debe tener un valor fijo asignado para poder funcionar, por ejemplo:

---

```
protected $token = 100;
```

**Opción 2**

- Declara la propiedad sin un valor asignado
- Declara un método y retorna a la propiedad `token` dentro de este mismo igualándola con el resultado dinámico que ofrece el método `random_int()`
- Genera una instancia de la clase con el objeto `$obj`
- imprime en pantalla lo que el objeto `$obj` accediendo al método `aleatorio()` retorna